# javascript calculate the total from html code

Tags: javascript

I HAVE

```
<tr>
<td nowrap="" align="right" id="n_852" class="tab ">1</td>
<td nowrap="" align="right" id="n_853" class="tab ">2</td>
<td nowrap="" align="right" id="n_854" class="tab ">3</td>
<td nowrap="" align="right" id="n_855" class="tab ">4</td>

</tr>
```

In js Can loop through out array `n_i` and calculate the total `1+2+3+4`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBLzp/

You could make it more restrictive by changing `*` to `td`

```
var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("*"),
    partial = new RegExp('n_','g'),
    total = 0;

for(var i=0; i< elements.length;i++){
    if(elements[i].id.match(partial)){
        total+= parseInt(elements[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function doSum()
{
  var stillGoing = true;
  var sum = 0;
  var i = 852;
  while (stillGoing)
  {
    var element = document.getElementById('n_' + i);
    if (element != null)
    {
      sum += parseInt(element.innerHTML);
    }
    else
    {
      stillGoing = false;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: -1 Assumption that there are no gaps is a poor one. Also it doesn't work (even if you start at `852`).

Comment: Sorry.  Question originally started with n_0.  But whatever index you start with should be irrelevant.  Code base provided seems to imply no gaps, though it is an assumption, it doesn't seem to be a poor one considering the information given.

Comment: yes,sorry for update the question,However it should better if dont care about the init i